# TTS on android with python

Tags: python, android

I have a lot of trouble getting any sort of TTS on android to work.
I'm using Kivy for the user interface.
So far I have tried gTTS, espeak and the pyJNius method.
The last one doesn't give any runtime error, but it also doesn't play any sound:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

import android
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
request_permissions([Permission.INTERNET])

class MyWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        from jnius import autoclass
        Locale = autoclass('java.util.Locale')
        PythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')
        TextToSpeech = autoclass('android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech')
        tts = TextToSpeech(PythonActivity.mActivity, None)

        # Play something in english
        tts.setLanguage(Locale.US)
        tts.speak('Hello World.', TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, None)

        # Queue something in french
        tts.setLanguage(Locale.FRANCE)
        tts.speak('Bonjour tout le monde.', TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, None)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

MyApp().run()
```

I'm also open for different solutions. The app is for personal use only so I don't care much how it is done. But german must be supported.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```py
import android
droid=android.Android()
droid.ttsSpeak("hello world")
```

You import the main android module, you create an instance and call the ttsSpeak method with the text you want spoken as an argument.

You can use this on android devices by installing SL4A (python for android) app or QPython app from play store.

If you are using QPython, use this to import android:

```py
import androidhelper.sl4a as android
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation along with your code

Answer (score -1):

Turns out, that the text to speech needs some time for initialization and cannot be used directly after initialization. That's why the example didn't produce any sound.